# Report pdf library for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, report, export-to-pdf

is there a library for nodejs/javascript to create dinamically pdf report as Ireport jasper report in Java ? I need to create dinamically pdf report in my nodejs webapp.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jsreport-core](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-core) package for this

```
var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()

jsreport.init().then(function () {     
   return jsreport.render({ 
       template: { 
           content: '<h1>Hello {{:foo}}</h1>', 
           engine: 'jsrender', 
           recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
        }, 
        data: { 
            foo: "world"
        }
    }).then(function(resp) {
     //prints pdf with headline Hello world
     console.log(resp.content.toString())
   });
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
})
```

This just simply wraps javascript templating engines and html to pdf converters. However it adds also many features on top of it like visual designer which you can use.

PS: I'm the author of [jsreport](http://jsreport.net)

Comment: Hi Jan great library ...  i read some days ago that http://jsreport.net/ is not opensource .... your version is open source ? What differ ?

Comment: jsreport-core and the most of the extensions are LGPL or MIT licensed. Only the official distribution - jsreport package has commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the combination of `html-pdf` and `handlebars` for that.
I generate an HTML report with `handlebars` and I let the `html-pdf` module generate a nice PDF from that.

Links:

[HTML-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)
[Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)